# How can I do to see "The text is saved." after clicking on submit on my modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and I am trying to have only this text on my modal after clicking on submit : "The text is saved.". Di you know how can I do to get that ?

I mean I have that :

[image: Initial]

and when I cick on submit I want that :

[image: Goal]

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";
import { ModalButton } from "react-modal-button";

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="title">React Modal Button</h1>
    <hr />

    <ModalButton
      buttonClassName="button"
      windowClassName="window-container"
      height={400}
      modal={(props) => (
        <Fragment>
          <header className="modal-card-head">Title</header>
          <div className="modal-card-body">
            Content
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" />
            <hr />
            <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="e.g. Hello world" />
          </div>
          <footer className="modal-card-foot u-justify-content--flex-end ">
            <button onClick={props.closeModal} className="button">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button className="button is-primary">Submit</button>
          </footer>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    >
      Open Modal
    </ModalButton>

    <hr />
    <ModalButton
      buttonClassName="button"
      windowClassName="window-container"
      modal={(props) => (
        <Fragment>
          <header className="modal-card-head">Title</header>
          <div className="modal-card-body">Content</div>
          <button onClick={props.closeModal} className="button">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    >
      Open Another Modal
    </ModalButton>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Or there [My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-button-forked-ejg5m?file=/src/index.js:0-1575)

Do you know how can I do ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

here is how you can do it, I have created a function named "handleSubmitClicked" that will be triggered whenever submit will be clicked, you can add code of show modal there

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";
import { ModalButton } from "react-modal-button";

function handleSubmitClicked() {
    alert('submit clicked')
}

const App = () => (

  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="title">React Modal Button</h1>
    <hr />

    <ModalButton
      buttonClassName="button"
      windowClassName="window-container"
      height={400}
      modal={(props) => (
        <Fragment>
          <header className="modal-card-head">Title</header>
          <div className="modal-card-body">
            Content
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" />
            <hr />
            <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="e.g. Hello world" />
          </div>
          <footer className="modal-card-foot u-justify-content--flex-end ">
            <button onClick={props.closeModal} className="button">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {handleSubmitClicked()}}
                    className="button is-primary">Submit</button>
          </footer>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    >
      Open Modal
    </ModalButton>

    <hr />
    <ModalButton
      buttonClassName="button"
      windowClassName="window-container"
      modal={(props) => (
        <Fragment>
          <header className="modal-card-head">Title</header>
          <div className="modal-card-body">Content</div>
          <button onClick={props.closeModal} className="button">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    >
      Open Another Modal
    </ModalButton>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```